# how to randomize my image view?

Tags: ios, image, swift, random

i want every time when i hit the button next a random image different of the current

**this is the code that i use but sometime the image didn't update:**

```
    @IBAction func nextBarButton(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {


    var image1 = UIImage(named: "RedBalloon1.jpg")
    var image2 = UIImage(named: "RedBalloon2.jpg")
    var image3 = UIImage(named: "RedBalloon3.jpg")
    var image4 = UIImage(named: "RedBalloon4.jpg")

    var images = [image1, image2, image3, image4]
    var indexPath = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(images.count)))
    currentIndex = indexPath
    if currentIndex == indexPath {
        indexPath = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(images.count)))
    }

    self.imageView.image = images[indexPath]
    self.balloonLabel.text = "\(count++) Balloon"


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, because of this line

```
currentIndex = indexPath
```

the next line always returns `true`:

```
if currentIndex == indexPath {
```

so indexPath is set on the next line

```
indexPath = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(images.count)))
```

and it has a 1 in 4 chance of being equal to the currently selected image.

You need a [`do-while` loop](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ControlFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH9-ID126), to make sure a new random number is selected for as long as necessary:

```
var images = [image1, image2, image3, image4]
var indexPath = 0
do {
    indexPath = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(images.count)))
} while currentIndex == indexPath
```

You can set `currentIndex = indexPath` afterwards.

Comment: i change the code but the image repeated ... then i update the value of the current index after randomizing  the indexPath and i think it works ....

Comment: Yes, you're right. I forgot to mention that, I thought it was obvious.

Comment: Note that in Swift 2 this will be [`repeat-while`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH33-ID433) instead of `do-while`.

Answer (score 0):

**this is how it's work for me :**

@IBAction func nextBarButton(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

```
    var image1 = UIImage(named: "RedBalloon1.jpg")
    var image2 = UIImage(named: "RedBalloon2.jpg")
    var image3 = UIImage(named: "RedBalloon3.jpg")
    var image4 = UIImage(named: "RedBalloon4.jpg")

    var images = [image1, image2, image3, image4]
    var indexPath = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(images.count)))
    while currentIndex == indexPath {
        indexPath = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(images.count)))
    }
```

> currentIndex = indexPath

```
    self.imageView.image = images[indexPath]
    self.balloonLabel.text = "\(count++) Balloon"


}
```